# Thymeleaf not working for camelcase class fields

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have Spring Boot controller which return list of object and I am using thymeleaf to display records ine html with code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>AllRecords</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Showing all records</h3>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Publised At</td>
            <td>Author</td>

        </tr>
        <tr th:each="news : ${newsList}">
            <td th:text="${news?.title}">Title</td>
            <td th:text="${news.publishedAt}">Publised At</td>
            <td th:text="${news?.author}">Author</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thymeleaf was unable to parse "**publishedAt**, its showing below error

```
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException:
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "news.publishedAt" (template: "showNews" - line 19, col 8)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:290)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109)
```

looks like its not working of camel case letters. Not sure how to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the entire error, as well as your `news` object definition, so we can see what needs to change.

Comment: May be it's a typo "publishedAt" instead of "publisedAt"

Answer (score 0):

It was a mistake with getter method, it was not inline with variable name, after changing getter thymeleaf was able to parse it correctly, silly mistake.